# How to make a live search using two streams of terms in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

What I learned from the Angular 2 docs is how to make a live search using one stream of terms (a search with only one parameter).

```
private searchTermStream = new Subject<string>();
search(term: string) { this.searchTermStream.next(term); }
items: Observable<string[]> = this.searchTermStream
  .debounceTime(300)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap((term: string) => this.wikipediaService.search(term));
```

What I need is making a live search for Restaurants with two parameters (I have already created a Rest webservice accepting two parameters: term and region, and returning list of available Restaurants).

Answer (score 0):

Use `combineLatest()` to create an Observable... combining the latest value of the two original observables.

```
private termObservable = new Subject<string>();
private regionObservable = new Subject<string>();
private criteriaObservable = 
    Observable.combineLatest(this.termObservable, 
                             this.regionObservable, 
                             (term, region) => {term, region});
```

Then, just as you're doing in your question, you can use that `criteriaObservable` to implement the search. The function passed to `switchMap()` will take an object containing the latest entered term and the latest entered region.

Make sure to pass a comparison function to `distinctUntilChanged()`, because it uses `===` to compare values by default, and you rather want to tuples of term/region to be equal when both terms and regions are equal:

```
items: Observable<string[]> = this.criteriaObservable
  .debounceTime(300)
  .distinctUntilChanged((o1, o2) => o1.term === o2.term && o1.region === o2.region)
  .switchMap(criteria => this.restaurantService.search(criteria.term, criteria.region));
```

Comment: And how about the **search** itself? How to combine these two statements `this.termObservable .next(term)` and `this.regionObservable.next(region)`?